# Can a portable bedroom fan be slowed down?

Tags: electric-motor

I have a Vornado Heavy Duty Shop Fan in a bedroom for the purpose of making white noise at night to help sleep.  The speed switch only has a medium speed and high speed.  I wish there was an option for a slow speed, but it does not have this.

Is there any way to add some electrical device between the wall circuit and the fan plug that would reduce the voltage going to the fan, so that it would run at a slower speed?

[image]

Comment: I think we'd have to know what kind of motor they're using to be sure...-. Theoretically a motor-rated dimmer -- like the speed controls sold for ceiling fans -- might work. You could mount that in a box for safety, and split an extension cord to feed into and out of it, and see if it works. *Make sure the wires have adequate strain relief and that insulation can't get worn on any edges.* and that the wattage rating is high enough to handle the fan.

Comment: Seconded that we'd need to know the motor type -- some motors may be speed-switchable, but not rated for use with solid-state fan controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have once made a lamp with a light dimmer enclosed in a PVC box. If you get a box and make holes for wires then wire a fan dimmer to it, you can precisely control it's speed. But make sure it is dimmable. If it doesnt say "non-dimmable" or something like that, it should be dimmable.
EDIT: Since it has an integrated dimmer, it is very likely to be dimmable.